# TypeScript error Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting this error:

```
  Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ foo: string; bar: string; }'.ts(7053)
```

In this code:

```
const CATEGORY_COLORS = {
  foo: '#6f79F6',
  bar: '#4fA0E9',
};

const CATEGORY_LABELS = {
  foo: 'FOO',
  bar: 'BAR',
};

const ItemRenderer = ({ item }: ItemRendererPropsType): React.ReactElement => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Tag color={CATEGORY_COLORS[item.category]}>
        {CATEGORY_LABELS[item.category]}
      </Tag>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The error is when I hover over either `CATEGORY_COLORS[item.category]` or `CATEGORY_LABELS[item.category]` with TypeScript. How do I resolve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a raw object is defined in Typescript (e.g. CATEGORY_LABELS) - it won't allow for indexed access (e.g. CATEGORY_LABELS[key]) where key is a string.  In your example, I assume that `item.category` is of type `string`.

Either `item.category` should be of type `keyof typeof CATEGORY_LABELS` or you need to redefine CATEGORY_LABELS to allow for indexing by a random string, but that is less typesafe, since you aren't guaranteeing that you will pass in a valid key.

```
const CATEGORY_LABELS: Record<string, string> = {
  foo: 'FOO',
  bar: 'BAR',
};
```

Comment: Now it says my value `item.category` may be null, do you know how to fix that? `Object is possibly 'null' Type 'null' cannot be used as an index type`

Comment: @alien can you share the definition of `ItemRendererPropsType` in the example?

Comment: Without that - I'd assume that checking for falsey value before using it would resolve the issue


```
  <Tag color={CATEGORY_COLORS[item.category]}>
        {item.category && CATEGORY_LABELS[item.category]}
   </Tag>

```

Answer (score 1):

You can also cast it as `{CATEGORY_LABELS[item.category as keyof typeof CATEGORY_LABELS]}`

---

This way, you are telling Typescript that the index should be keys of the types in CATEGORY_LABEL and the error will go away.